# Headers de datatable se posicionan mal | table responsive materialize

Tags: jquery, materialize, datatable, responsive

Estoy probando datatables con materialize, estaba probando la clase `responsive-table` en una tabla que tengo inicializada con datatable.

El problema que veo es que al momento de que cargue la pagina desde una pantalla mediana hacia arriba se mira bien la tabla, pero cuando se hace mas pequeña la pantalla y se aplica la clase `responsive-table` los headers de la tabla se posicionan de una forma desordenada, unos en el medio otros a la derecha otros mas a la izquierda, al ver el ejemplo lo entenderan mejor. Pero si se carga la pagina desde una pantalla pequeña en la que ya este aplicada la clase `responsive-table` y agrandamos la pantalla si se ordenan de forma correcta los headers se haga mas pequeña o grande.

[Aquí](https://codepen.io/Villatoro/pen/pLBEYO?editors=1010) les dejo el ejemplo para que me entiendan mejor, de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Le he estado echando un ojo al código y no veo nada raro, no obstante si usas la funcion inspeccionar de Google Chrome y echas un vistazo al código generado vas a ver que te está metiendo un style con un width al  y le esta afectando un "ordering".

No se si estás trabajando con un IDE o directamente con codepen...si es así, lo mismo es codepen quien esta causando tu fallo...si no es así, asegurate de que estas usando una versión actualizada de DataTable porque ya te digo que he analizado el código y he estado tocando y cambiando parametros y no encuentro que puede ser y mira que las he trabajado...Si lo averiguas publícalo, un saludo.